# eclipse gray background instead of white in ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, linux-mint

Until recently, I used to develop Java using eclipse in windows environment.

Now I moved to Mint 17 (Ubuntu based) and the background of eclipse's editor is now gray instead of white.

Is there a way to fix this?

regards,
Id

Answer (score 0):

You could change your theme in Mint but I don't recommend that.
You could also download a new theme
Or...
In eclipse go to

> Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors

In the list under "Appearance color options" choose Background color and **uncheck** the "System Default".

The color should automatically change to white. If it didn't change simply click the color and choose your desired color.